# Stopping the Facebook Like dialog box flickering where it overlaps a Google Maps API v2 div

Tags: google-maps, facebook-like

I have just implemented AddThis to place, among other things, a Facebook Like button above my Google Map (not on top of - higher in the page).

When I click the Like button and getting the sharing dialog I get an annoying flickering where things overlap.

I don't believe I can provide an [example](http://www.trailhunger.com/course/35) without linking, I'm sorry.

Is there any way to control this without just changing the page layout?

Comment: Yes - I cross posted it. I even said I cross-posted it. I waited a day on facebook.so.com and saw nothing so put it on so.com. Frankly, I'm confused as to whether they get a different audience or not. Certainly the tag counts are different.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by adding
style="opacity: 1;filter: alpha(opacity=100);"
to the addthis_button_facebook_like anchor.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem with the link dialog box flickering where it overlapped a fb comment box.  Used Daco's code and it works great.

```
.addthis_button_facebook_like {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
 }
```

Tested on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.